# CryptGetProvParam всегда возвращает TRUE при перечислении контейнеров криптопровайдере "Код безопасности CSP"

Tags: delphi, winapi, криптопро, cryptoapi, csp

При попытке получить список контейнеров в криптопровайдере "Код безопасности CSP" (dwProvType = 90), функция CryptGetProvParam постоянно возвращает True при dwFlag:= CRYPT_NEXT. Тем самым получается бесконечный цикл. Хотя в документации сказано, что при возвращении False и GetLastError == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS, в списке нет больше элементов для перечисления. По факту криптопровайдер возвращает всегда только первый элемент, игнорируя флаг CRYPT_NEXT. Провайдер КриптоПро при этом отрабатывает как положено.

```pascal
    procedure getContainers(const dwProvType, dwFlags: DWORD; var containers: TList<string>);
    var
      hCryptProv: Winapi.NCrypt.HCRYPTPROV;
      dwFlag: DWORD;
      pdwDataLen: DWORD;
      pbData: PByte;
    begin
      if not Assigned(containers) then Exit;

      containers.Clear;

      if (CryptAcquireContext(hCryptProv,
                              nil,
                              nil,
                              dwProvType,
                              CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) then begin

        if (hCryptProv <> 0) then try

          dwFlag:= CRYPT_FIRST;
          pdwDataLen:= 0;

          if (CryptGetProvParam(hCryptProv, PP_ENUMCONTAINERS, nil, pdwDataLen, dwFlags or dwFlag)) then begin

            GetMem(pbData, pdwDataLen); try

              while True do begin

                if Assigned(pbData) then

                  if CryptGetProvParam(hCryptProv,
                                PP_ENUMCONTAINERS,
                                pbData,
                                pdwDataLen,
                                dwFlags or dwFlag) then begin

                    dwFlag:= CRYPT_NEXT;
                    containers.Add(String(PAnsiChar(pbData)));

                  end else Break;

              end;

            finally
              FreeMem(pbData, pdwDataLen);
            end;
          end;

        finally
          CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        end;

      end;
    end;
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что в dwFlags в функцию не передаёте CRYPT_FIRST в том числе? Что если вместо `dwFlags or dwFlag` оставить только `dwFlag`? Тем более, как следует [отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgetprovparam), там больше ничего и не поддерживается (кроме CRYPT_FIRST и CRYPT_NEXT).

Comment: Уверен, в отладчике это хорошо видно, помимо этого, для того же КриптоПро провайдера можно передавать такие флаги как CRYPT_FQCN = 0x10 и CRYPT_UNIQUE = 0x08 (что делается через dwFlags), меняющие вывод контейнеров. И даже если оставить только dwFlag, устанавливая сперва CRYPT_FIRST, а потом CRYPT_NEXT, это никак не влияет, возвращается все также первый контейнер в бесконечном цикле

Comment: Ну тогда это похоже на баг в криптопровайдере. Или у него какие-то свои значения для CRYPT_FIRST и CRYPT_NEXT. Документация с примерами есть у него? Примеры оттуда работают?

Comment: Документация есть, но готовых примеров ней нет, только описания параметров и возможных флагов, следуя которым, получаем точно такой же бесконечный цикл. Так что видимо это все таки баг. Буду пробовать на других конфигурациях

Comment: Попробуйте написать в поддержку разработчикам?.. Продукт платный, насколько я понимаю.